# Flutter use InteractiveViewer to crop an image

Tags: image, flutter, crop

I'd like to use InteractiveViewer in order to implement my own image crop.

Steps:

1. The user pans and scales an image, using InteractiveViewer
2. The user clicks a button
3. Get the "viewable" part of the InteractiveViewer content (bounding box)
4. Using [this library](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image), crop the image
5. Resize the cropped image (scale down), maybe compress it, and upload to my server

I fail to understand step 3: getting the "viewable" part of the InteractiveViewer content

Comment: Why don't you use `image_cropper` package

Comment: I've tested it. It works fine, but I can't customize it (visually) to my needs. Trying to see if I can easily create a simple widget of my own

Answer (score 0):

I have been on the search how to do this myself!

Using the [InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/builder.html)https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/builder.html got me far - by referencing the Quad that gets passed in, I was able to get the screen coordinates of the viewport. It worked well when there is no scaling, but the coordinates and seem to drift when there is scaling and I could not troubleshoot what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

After dedicating substantial effort, I managed to implement image cropping in Flutter using the GestureDetector. I'm sharing my code here in the hope that it can be beneficial for others in the future. It's worth mentioning that I'm relatively new to Flutter development, and a significant portion of this code was crafted with assistance from ChatGPT. There may be more straightforward approaches to achieving the same goal, and some parts of the code could potentially be optimized.

Included is a screenshot to provide clarity on the code's functionality. The blue box is draggable via the blue dots. Once positioned, clicking the blue button triggers a behind-the-scenes process, cropping the image and sending it to a new screen for display
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'dart:typed_data';

class CropImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final File? image;
  const CropImage({Key? key, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CropImage> createState() => _CropImageState();
}

class _CropImageState extends State<CropImage> {
  late Future<List<int>> imageSize;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imageSize = loadImageInfo(widget.image!);
  }

  List<Ball> balls = [
    Ball(position: Offset(50, 50)),
    Ball(position: Offset(50, 150)),
    Ball(position: Offset(150, 50)),
    Ball(position: Offset(150, 150)),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Crop the page'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[400],
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.check),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => CropImageUsingImage(
                    balls: balls,
                    path: widget.image!,
                    imageSize: imageSize,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
        future: imageSize,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            List<int> size = snapshot.data!;
            double aspectRatio = size[0] / size[1];

            return Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / aspectRatio,
                  child: Image.file(
                    widget.image!,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
                  for (int j = i + 1; j < balls.length; j++)
                    Line(start: balls[i].position, end: balls[j].position),
                for (var ball in balls)
                  Positioned(
                    left: ball.position.dx,
                    top: ball.position.dy,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        setState(() {
                          ball.updatePosition(
                              details.delta, context, imageSize);
                        });
                      },
                      child: ball.build(),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Ball {
  Offset position;
  double ballSize = 30;

  Ball({required this.position});

  void updatePosition(
      Offset delta, dynamic context, Future<List<int>> imageSize) async {
    List<int> size = await imageSize;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    double newX = (position.dx + delta.dx);
    double newY = (position.dy + delta.dy);

    double aspectRatio = size[0] / size[1];

    newX = newX.clamp(0.0, screenWidth - 30); // Clamp within the range 0 to 1
    newY = newY.clamp(
        0.0,
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / aspectRatio -
            30); // Clamp within the range 0 to 1

    position = Offset(newX, newY);
  }

  Widget build() {
    return Container(
      width: ballSize, // Set your desired size
      height: ballSize, // Set your desired size
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Line extends StatelessWidget {
  final Offset start;
  final Offset end;

  Line({required this.start, required this.end});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: LinePainter(start: start, end: end),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<int>> loadImageInfo(File file) async {
  var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(file.readAsBytesSync());
  int imageWidth = decodedImage.width;
  int imageHeight = decodedImage.height;
  return [imageWidth, imageHeight];
}

class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset start;
  final Offset end;

  LinePainter({required this.start, required this.end});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;

    final adjustedStart = start + const Offset(15, 15); // Adjust for the center
    final adjustedEnd = end + const Offset(15, 15); // Adjust for the center
    canvas.drawLine(adjustedStart, adjustedEnd, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class CropImageUsingImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Ball> balls;
  final File path;
  final Future<List<int>> imageSize;

  const CropImageUsingImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.balls,
    required this.path,
    required this.imageSize,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
      future: imageSize,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return buildCroppedImage(snapshot.data!, context);
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildCroppedImage(List<int> size, BuildContext context) {
    final aspectRatio = size[0] / size[1];

    final imageWidth = size[0].toDouble();
    final imageHeight = size[1].toDouble();

    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double screenHeight = screenWidth / aspectRatio;

    final imgPoints = balls.map((ball) {
      final double x = ball.position.dx / screenWidth * imageWidth;
      final double y = ball.position.dy / screenHeight * imageHeight;
      return img.Point(x, y);
    }).toList();

    final topLeft = imgPoints[0];
    final topRight = imgPoints[2];
    final bottomLeft = imgPoints[1];
    final bottomRight = imgPoints[3];

    final img.Image image = img.decodeJpg(path.readAsBytesSync())!;
    final croppedImage = img.copyRectify(
      image,
      topLeft: topLeft,
      topRight: topRight,
      bottomLeft: bottomLeft,
      bottomRight: bottomRight,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Cropped Image'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(croppedImage))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```